# Adding Spanish language versions of a few pages

Tags: seo, multilingual, translation

I have an English language website which ranks well in its niche in North America and some other countries.

I noticed that a few pages in particular get a high portion of Spanish speaking users - mostly commenting asking for a Spanish version of this page.

I was thinking about having the few pages professionally translated, and creating additional versions of those pages in the other language. So for example, let's say the English page is:

```
/travel/things-to-do-in-mexico
```

I would translate the title and slug, as well as the content, and create another page with identical, but professionally translated content from the English version:

```
/viajes/cosas-que-hacer-en-México
```

Again, I would be having it properly and professionally translated, so don't get hung up on this example.

Is this the best way to go about achieving the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Marking it up in sitemap:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

Meta tags:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

The problem is with navbar and if you use some kind of automation to "related pages", social media and all the other stuff.  If it is  just for a few static ones the sitemap and meta tags are sufficient.

A little more work if you want a "full website experience" instead of just a few specific articles.

Comment: I want to understand more about this stub. Please elaborate "A little more work if you want a "full website experience" instead of just a few specific articles." It would be really helpful as I am facing the same problem.